# Merge files including their svn history

Tags: svn, merge

I have two java files in an svn repository, a class and its abstract parent class, and I want to merge them, so that only one class belongs in the repository.

Merging the code itself is no problem, but I want to preserve the history of both files, when I delete one of them.

Is there a way to merge the history using svn?

Comment: The history of the two sources is stored inside the repository anyway. There is nothing you have to do, since the repository does not forget where that code comes from. If you however mean that you want to _double_ that information to create a new commit message that holds all that information then no, there is no direct way to do that (since it makes little sense). You'd have to extract the history of both source trees and combine the commit messages to a new text you then use as a commit message for the checkin uploading the merge itself.

Comment: I adapted the description. I want to get rid of one of the files, so that after merging, only one file stays in the repository.

Comment: Ah, ok, I missinterpreted the term 'merge', sorry. That is _not_ a merge as in svn talk, but an implementation level merging of the code. That is indeed something different.

Comment: There is some interesting information in the first answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557658/using-subversion-how-can-i-cut-from-one-file-and-paste-to-another-preserving-hi

Comment: I thought about that switch of svn merge too but I don't see how I can use svn merge for two working copies